# FirebaseMessaging on iOS - how to get topic through which a message was sent?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using `FirebaseMessaging` with topic subscription on iOS.

I'm receiving messages in the `application(_ application:, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:, fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler:)` method as expected, but I can't find a way to get the topic name through which a given message was sent.

Is it possible? I can't find anything like that in the `userInfo` value that I get in that method.

On Android it's easy: `RemoteMessage.getFrom()` returns exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No information about the topic is included in the data that Firebase Cloud Messaging delivers to your iOS application code. If you want to know the topic, you'll have to include that in the payload that you send.